# Who should be on the twitter stackexchange UX list?

Tags: discussion

I created a [Twitter list of people on UX](https://twitter.com/#!/Rahul/ux-stackexchange/members) a while ago and it would be nice to expand on it and get some more followers. Does anyone know of more UX members who could be added to the list, or anyone else I've missed?

Comment: I don't know if I should be on it but here's mine: [@naoisegolden](http://twitter.com/naoisegolden). I tweet about web development in general

Comment: Not sure what you are particularly looking for but mine is @mervinjohnsingh ,I mostly tweet about usability and UX

Comment: As far as I'm concerned any UX SE user can be on the list.

Comment: I'm @CreativeNewman

Comment: I'd recommend [@ewindram](http://twitter.com/ewindram) or even myself [@podlipensky](http://twitter.com/podlipensky) ;)

Comment: Added everyone. @PaulPodlipensky Elizabeth is on UX?

Comment: As far as I know - yes, she was famous UX in Google, but now she is working for Quora. Her tweets are not always professional, but some of them really valuable.

Comment: @PaulPodlipensky I know who she is; I meant, is she a member of UX StackExchange? Because I can't find her

Comment: Oh, I don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

here's a few more @cloudforest, @paulolyslager, @SirTapTap

Comment: Added! Thanks Roger.

Answer (score 0):

[@ctomlin](https://twitter.com/#!/ctomlin) is a prolific one that doesn't seem to be on the list.